# TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', 'groups') in keras.models load_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

After training a model using Google Colab, I downloaded it using the following command (inside Google Colab):

```
model.save('model.h5')
from google.colab import files
files.download('model.h5')
```

My problem is that when I try to load the downloaded *model.h5* using my local machine (outside Google Colab), I get the following error:

[input]

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model(model.h5)
```

[output]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    model = load_model(filepath = 'saved_model/model2.h5',custom_objects=None,compile=True, )
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 184, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 177, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 105, in deserialize
    return deserialize_keras_object(
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 369, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 397, in from_config
    layer = layer_module.deserialize(layer_config,
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 105, in deserialize
    return deserialize_keras_object(
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 375, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(cls_config)
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 655, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 582, in __init__
    super(Conv2D, self).__init__(
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 121, in __init__
    super(Conv, self).__init__(
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 456, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 294, in __init__
    generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs)
  File "/home/lucasmirachi/anaconda3/envs/myenviron/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 792, in validate_kwargs
    raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'groups')
```

Does anyone know what is this **'groups'** keyword argument not understood?
Instead of using `from keras.models` I have tried using `from tensorflow.keras.models` but I had no success, I got the same error.
In both Google Colab and on my local machine I'm running Keras '2.4.3'

*Thank you all in advance!*

Comment: are you using `tf.keras` in  colab?

Comment: I have tried using tf.keras and only keras in colab and got the same problem

Comment: You need to use `keras` or `tf.keras` in both colab and your local system because they are can't be used with one another. So if you are using colab with `tf.keras`,  use local with `tf.keras` only and vice versa.

Comment: I just downloaded both models (one using `keras` and one using `tensorflow.keras`) and tried using `from keras.models import load_model` and `from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model` to load it on my local machine, and got the same error message.

Comment: I get the same exact error from doing the same exact thing (building & downloading in Colab then trying to load it on my local machine). I used tensorflow.keras for both notebooks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I commented earlier saying I had the same exact error from doing the same exact thing. I just solved it by upgrading both tensorflow and keras on my local machine

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install --upgrade keras
```

The error was probably due to differing versions of the packages between Colab and local machine. Hope this works for you, too.

Comment: Upgrading them did solve my problem as well! Thanks Sam!!

Comment: Glad to be of help! Hope all goes well with your project!

Comment: I have the same problem on colab, tried your solution but I am still receiving the error. Plus I always use tf.keras inside my project

Comment: Yup, it's a version mismatch issue. In version 2.3, the 'groups' argument was added to Conv layers (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.3/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D?hl=en). This argument is not present in 2.2. (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.2/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D)

Comment: Thank you for saving me from going bonkers. I have two conda environments. Was using the out of date one.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue because I was saving and loading the model with different versions of tensorflow. I saved a model with tf 2.3.0 then loaded it with tf 2.1.0.

I made sure that both saving and loading use the same venv which fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue so I checked for the versions of tensorflow and keras in google-colaboratory and found the following:

[image]

I solved the issue by installing tensorflow and keras with the commands below in my anaconda environment:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1
pip install Keras==2.4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay on the same tf version, a workaround is `model.load_weights("model_path")`. Not the best solution, but it works

Answer (score 0):

I have in colab (Google) tensorflow version 2.9.2
and in my Raspberry 4  tensorflow versio 2.4.1. So diferent versions.
I made in colab a pre-training model VGG19 with input_shape(220,220,3). And I classificated 2 types image.

I SOLVED like this:

In colab (making model):

```
# serialize model to JSON
model_json =  loaded_model2.to_json()
with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/extract/model_5.json', "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5

loaded_model2.save_weights('/content/drive/MyDrive/model_5.h5')
print("Saved model to disk")
```

Then, in my Raspberry I create a model.

```
model_new = tf.keras.Sequential()
model_new.add(tf.keras.applications.VGG19(include_top=false, weights='imagenet',pooling='avg',input_shape=(220,220,3)))
model_new.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation="softmax"))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGC(0,004)
model_new.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And then, I load weights from colab in this model made in my Raspberry 4. Only .h5 file with weights:

```
model_new.load_weights('/home/pi/projects/models/model_5.h5)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33579902)